# IE 11 CSS Float is not inline

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

In Chrome two divs floated left are inline and the right size.

However in Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) they are no longer inline and the logo seems to be larger in height.

I have posted the code https://jsfiddle.net/3e8bwqaf/

```
#logoBar, #siteHeaderBar {
    float: left;
}
```

I tried a bunch of clears and overflow on different elements but I still was unable to get it to look right on IE11

[Chrome on top, IE11 on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj2iZ.jpg)

How would you fix the float where it would not be stacked on top of each other?

Comment: It's related to the svg. You can set height on it, e.g. style="height:26px"

Comment: Oh ... I thought I tried that.That works perfectly, thanks @eirikh

Comment: Np, I've [posted it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37999890/543549) you can accept if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to the svg as it's rendered with a 1:1 ratio in IE. You can set height on it, e.g. style="height:26px" to make it work in IE as well.